# Sorting FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on Client Side

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to sort FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on the TIME BASIS. I'm working on That Application so whenever new Message comes then That Dialog goes on The Top of the Layout, it also contain time of Sending the Message so The message which is new Then that should be in The Top of the Recyclerview. So **So How Can i sort The FirebaseRecyclerAdapter on the Time Basis**
**Here is me Code**

```
madapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<user, contact.UserViewHolder>(user.class, R.layout.activity_dialogs_list, contact.UserViewHolder.class, muserref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final UserViewHolder viewHolder, user model, final int position) {
            final String ais = model.getName();
            viewHolder.setName(model.getName());
            final String b = model.groupId;
            //Toast.makeText(contact.this,viewHolder.getLayoutPosition(),LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("LastMessage").child(b);
            mref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        val=lmlm;
                        HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        val = (String) hashmap.get("lastm");
                        Long role = (Long) hashmap.get("timestampCreated");
                        String lastsender = (String) hashmap.get("LastmessageSender");
                        getTimeago getTimeAgo = new getTimeago();
                        String lastSeenTime = getTimeAgo.getTimeAgo(role);
                        //SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
                        //String dateAsString = sdf.format (role);
                        //change(position);
                        //   swape(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

                        if (val.length() > 40) {
                            String nawa = val.substring(0, 40);
                            viewHolder.setLastmessage((nawa + "..."));
                            viewHolder.setLastTime(lastSeenTime);

                        } else {
                            viewHolder.setLastmessage(val);
                            viewHolder.setLastTime(lastSeenTime);

                        }
                        //viewHolder.setLastmessage(val);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            mimage = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Image").child(b);
            mimage.keepSynced(true);
            mimage.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapShot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashmap = (HashMap) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                        final String vala = (String) hashmap.get("image");

                        viewHolder.setImage(vala, getApplicationContext());
                        /// //viewHolder.setImage(val,getApplicationContext());
                        //viewHolder.setImage(vala);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toast.makeText(contact.this,"Something Went wrong",LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });




                }
            });
        }

    };
    mUserlist.setAdapter(madapter);
    madapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**And Here is My Holder**
   `
public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
    View mview;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public UserViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mview = itemView;

    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        TextView username = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.dialogName);
        username.setText(name);
    }

    public void setLastmessage(String lastmessage) {

        TextView set = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.dialogLastMessage);
        set.setText(lastmessage);


    }

    public void setLastTime(String lastTime) {
        TextView time = (TextView) mview.findViewById(R.id.dialogDate);
        time.setText(lastTime);
    }


    public void setImage(final String vala, final Context applicationContext) {
        final CircleImageView cm = (CircleImageView) mview.findViewById(R.id.dialogAvatar);
        Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(vala).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(cm, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(vala).into(cm);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError() {
                Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(vala).into(cm);
            }
        });


    }
```

`

[So if new Message comes in SE Comps then that Dialog Show goes on The Top of RecyclerView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ksxV.png)**So How can i get that please Help**

Comment: Can you post your firebase database structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [orderByChild](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#orderByChild) function to sort firebase list data?

ref.orderByChild('< time_key >')

OrderByChild will work with [ChildEventListner](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data)

[check this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data)

Comment: What should I enter in time key

Comment: Servervalue.timestamp

Comment: ref.orderByChild("timestampCreated").

Comment: it's not Working @Anurag_Meena

Comment: If you will attach value listener to reference then you will all data (not sorted) then you have to sort it in Android code. You should use childEventListner. Did you try that?

Comment: No. I'll try to

Comment: it's not working. I think my database structure is not suitable for orderbychild(  ) method. Any other method is there to get the solution

Comment: Can you please share sample db here

Comment: can u have me ur phone number or email id to discuss the problem please...

Comment: anuragmeena92@gmail.com